# Kubernetes ingress error: redirected you too many times

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have php5.6 application running on kubernetes and exposed using ingress. Php application contains nginx and php5.6 fpm. When i expose service using `kubectl port-forward <service> 9090:80` "localhost:9090/admin" redirect to "localhost:9090/admin/index/login" page as expected. This redirection rule is not defined in nginx file. It happens internally by php application. But when i expose service using ingress, and hit "www.demo.example.com/admin" it redirects to "www.demo.example.com/admin/index/login" but gives error `redirected you too many times`. Below is ingress file that i'm using. I'm trying to figure out why this is happening but no luck.
No error is in error.log but in access.log
`"GET /admin/index/login HTTP/1.1" 301 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<ip> Safari/537.36"`

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: php-web-ingress
  labels:
    name: php-web-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "www.demo.example.com"
    http:
      paths: 
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: www-service
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /wp-admin
          backend:
            serviceName: wordpress
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /admin/
          backend:
            serviceName: php-web-service
            servicePort: 80
-----------------------------------------------
Nginx.conf
server { 
    listen      80; 
    server_name www.demo.example.com; 

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log; 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; 

    root  /sites/www/public/; 

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 
    } 

    location ~ \.php$ { 
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock; 
        fastcgi_index index.php; 
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_script_name; 
        include fastcgi_params; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your PHP code might be doing this. Check how it is redirecting. Also check your browser inspector Net tab to find more details.

Comment: All is good from coding side. Problem is with ingress configuration or missing configuration :(